# Apache file permissions for PHP but not for direct access

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I installed an Apache server and am playing around with it a bit. What I can't figure out is how to properly set permissions for this setup:

I don't want my files to be externally accessible (i.e. `./files/file1.foo`) - there are many files in this directory and I don't want people to be able to read them. So far so good. `chmod o+r` enables reading and vice versa, in my case.

Then I have a PHP script that handles sessions with each user, who owns one of the files and should be able to view it, but only it, not the other files. Let's say the file is a picture. I would write `<?php ... echo "<img src=\"files/file5.foo\"> ?>` to show this file. But that wouldn't work, because the PHP doesn't have permissions to the file either.

What is the way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those requirements the best solution is to store the protected files outside of the public HTML and use a PHP script to serve them. The PHP can then check if the current user should be allowed to access the requested file or not.

Have a look at [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). For inline images, don't set the file transfer headers, just output the content (you can still output a content-type header but that isn't needed).

Comment: I can't get it to work. This code just shows me an icon for a broken image `<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile('/IMG_9760.JPG');
?>` - the image file has all permissions. If I comment out the header line, all I get is a text-dump of the file. :/

Comment: @MartinMelka I doubt that the image is located in the root directory of the operating system. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: @MartinMelka as jeroen suggested, check the path to the file. Also check that you have no whitespace being outputted (for example before the `<?php` tag) because any whitespace will break the showing of the file. Also try sending a `content-length` header so the browser knows how much data is coming.

Comment: yeah, it is in the root, I put it there just temporarily to test this out.

Comment: I guess I found where the problem was. I had a html page with some text and among it this php script, just outputting `readfile()`. When I put the script into a separate php file and put `<img src=fetchimage.php>`, it works. I'm just a beginner, so I didn't know this. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah yes, it has to be in its own file with no other output or whitespace :)

Comment: Forget the file system access rights for frontend-user, they are not applicable. You'll have to write code to distinguish your users, but the access to the server file system is always through the webserver.